# How to get the user ip in node js without using 3 rd party library?

Tags: node.js, express, server, ip, meanjs

I am trying to find the Ip address of the user.For that I wrote the code in server using a 3rd party but later I understood that the third party detects the ip of the server where it is located but not the client i.e where the client located.So here I am using node js as server.I used the following coe to get the ip

```
var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

But this giving me as

```
::1
```

But when I used the 3rd party I got my ip as

```
222.38.46.5
```

Can any one please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: `var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
     req.connection.remoteAddress || 
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;`

Comment: I am get ::1,still.

Comment: Are you testing it on `localhost` ?

Comment: Yes.,..........

Comment: Then it's correct. ::1 is localhost. You need to run it on a server to get the client's ip.

Comment: Can I check in network?

Comment: I mean in my test server console->network,

Comment: Yeah, that should give you the client's IP on Local network.

Comment: [This glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/get-my-ip-address) demonstrates a partial solution.